# My one element is overlaping other element

Tags: html, css, z-index, overlapping

I am a Beginner to web development.

I can't figure out how to bring my logo to front using CSS. I've already tried setting z-index to 1000 and position to relative, but it still fails.

Here I've provided full code because I was not able to figure Out where am I going wrong!

What should I do bring element to front?

¯\_(ツ)_/¯

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body{
    font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #9c27b0, #8ecdff);
}

.logo{
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    flex-basis: 20%;
    z-index: 1;
}
.logo img{
    width: 13vw;
    margin-left: 1vw;
    margin-top: 1vw;
}
nav{
    position: sticky;
}
.navbar{
    float: right;
}
.navbar ul{
    display: flex;
    list-style: none;
}
.navbar ul li{
    margin-top: 1.8vw;
    margin-right: 3vw;
}
.navbar ul li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
}
.info{
    z-index: 0;
    width: 60vw;
    height: 140vh;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: -10%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
#circle{
    width: 60vw;
    height: 140vh;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #ccc ;    
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Real Phone</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <nav>
            <div class="logo">
                <!-- I've commented the actual logo -->
                <!-- <img src="images/resourses/logo.png" alt=""> -->
                <h1>LOGO</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Phones</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Accessories</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Cart</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <div class="info">
            <div id="circle">
                <div class="feature" id="f1"></div>
                <div class="feature" id="f2"></div>
                <div class="feature" id="f3"></div>
                <div class="feature" id="f4"></div> 
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry! if my code is MESSY

Comment: What element is it that you want to bring to the front? Can you add a comment in your css code?

Comment: change `nav{position: sticky;}` to  `{position: relative;}`

Comment: Which images do you want to bring in front

Comment: @ SwiftLynx  I wanna bring (.logo) to front

Comment: @LaljiTadhani I tried but it didn't worked

Comment: @Aman I wanna bring (.logo) to front

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution didn't work because you were setting the `z-index` inside of the navigation element that was already behind the circle. `z-index` only applies to all elements inside the container, so only inside your `nav` element.

To fix the problem, set the `z-index` of `.info` to be behind everything else, so the `#circle` inside the `.info` is also behind everything else.

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body{
    font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #9c27b0, #8ecdff);
}

.logo{
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    flex-basis: 20%;
    z-index: 1;
}
.logo img{
    width: 13vw;
    margin-left: 1vw;
    margin-top: 1vw;
}
nav{
    position: sticky;
}
.navbar{
    float: right;
}
.navbar ul{
    display: flex;
    list-style: none;
}
.navbar ul li{
    margin-top: 1.8vw;
    margin-right: 3vw;
}
.navbar ul li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
}
.info{
    /* set the z-index of the entire info to be behind everything else */
    z-index: -1;
    width: 60vw;
    height: 140vh;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: -10%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
#circle{
    width: 60vw;
    height: 140vh;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #ccc ;    
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Real Phone</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <nav>
            <div class="logo">
                <!-- I've commented the actual logo -->
                <img src="images/resourses/logo.png" alt="">
                <h1>LOGO</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Phones</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Accessories</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Cart</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <div class="info">
            <div id="circle">
                <div class="feature" id="f1"></div>
                <div class="feature" id="f2"></div>
                <div class="feature" id="f3"></div>
                <div class="feature" id="f4"></div> 
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="info">
            <div id="circle">
                <div class="feature" id="f1"></div>
                <div class="feature" id="f2"></div>
                <div class="feature" id="f3"></div>
                <div class="feature" id="f4"></div> 
            </div>
        </div>
        <nav>
            <div class="logo">
                <!-- I've commented the actual logo -->
                <!-- <img src="images/resourses/logo.png" alt=""> -->
                <h1>LOGO</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Phones</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Accessories</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Cart</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
</body>
```

Basicaly, by putting the dev element with the info class before the nav, the browser will prioritize and display the nav over the info.

Comment: please add some explanation on how your answers answers an OP's question